# How do I create a ''droplet'' script in Win7 that runs a Notepad++ task on a CSV file

Tags: batch-file, notepad++, csv, spreadsheet, cells

I have recently asked a question on how to perform a neat little 'Find & Replace' task on my CSV media database files (a task i have to do at work on a daily basis). The question was answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1351587/how-do-i-copy-specific-selected-data-between-cells-in-a-csv-file-in-excel-or-not) if anyone is interested in the details.

I now want to be able to simply drag and drop my CSV file onto a droplet on the desktop that performs the Find and Replace Notepad++ task quickly and easily, so i can delegate this task to more junior members of staff at times when i'm away.

**Question:**

*How do I create a droplet in Win 7 that runs the following 'Find & Replace' command on any CSV file dropped onto it?*

[image]

Text:

*Find what:*

```
^([^,]*,(\d\d)_[^,]*,[^,]*)(?<!_\d\d),
```

*Replace with:*

```
$1_$2,
```

*Check:* Wrap around

*Check:* Regular expression

*Run:* Replace All

I am imagining that this could be a batch script (or any script of sorts) that will receive my CSV file as the input file by simply drag dropping it onto the script.

Comment: What exactly is a 'droplet'? Is it the same as a Shortcut?

Comment: Hi, i'm referring to a script that can receive the input file by dragging and dropping my CSV file onto it. I'm thinking this could be a batch script that would receive file "%~1" and open in Notepad++ to run the command I've requested, however i am really not knowledgeable enough in this area to know what the best thing to do here is? i will edit my question further clarify. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get it. As far as I know Notepad++ does not have such an option (http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches), so you may need to use other tooling such as AutoIt or a windows version of sed. I'm not an expert on either of these.

Comment: I'm open to any and all suggestions. Thanks everyone for all contributions towards this!

Comment: I don't know if the Notepad++ 'Find and Replace' function can be called from command line but i have recorded what i need to do as a macro within Notepad++. So i'm not sure if perhaps these macro's can be called in command line instead?

Comment: There's a plugin called NppExec that enables you to execute scripts using the 'Run' (F5) menu within Notepad++ but is this in any way usable within Win 7 CMD to do what i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 comes with PowerShell v2 which supports Regular Expressions with negative look behinds.

If I interpret your [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/bKoJJ1/1) correctly you want to apply the two digits `99_` leading the 2nd field to trail also the 3rd field, provided there isn't already a `_99` number. And leave the other lines/remainder of the line as is.

A batch file serving as a drop target (also handling multiple files):

```
:: SO_1352996.cmd
@Echo off
:Loop
If "%~1" equ "" goto :Eof
If not exist "%~1" (shift & goto :Loop)
Ren "%~f1" "%~n1_Original%~x1"
:: Use PowerShell as a tool to do the replace.
Powershell -NoP -C "(Get-Content '%~dpn1_Original%~x1') -replace '^([^,]*,(\d\d)_[^,]*,[^,]*)(?<!_\d\d),','$1_$2,' | Set-Content '%~f1'
Shift
Goto :Loop
```

file.csv before

```
test,12_blah,blubb,anything
test,34_blah,blu_34,doesn't matter
test,56_foo,bar,nevermind
```

and after dropping on the above batch.

```
test,12_blah,blubb_12,anything
test,34_blah,blu_34,doesn't matter
test,56_foo,bar_56,nevermind
```

The original file is saved with the additional extension `.bak`

Comment: Hi LotPings, I just copy pasted your code and saved as a batch script. When i try drag dropping the csv file it opens a cmd window and repeats the following 'A duplicate filename exists, or the file cannot be found'. Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: Maybe the modified or original file can be saved out with '_ORIGINAL' or '_MODIFIED'? Not sure how to change the script to do that.

Comment: Sorry there is a missing shift as the second last line, Corrected.

Comment: Incorporated the `_Original` appendix to the file name

Comment: That seems to have worked in modifying the database file. I had to copy the file to the desktop to do it though because the command window tells me 'UNC Paths not supported'. The place where all the CSVs are stored is a network location. Any way around that? I'm not too fussed if it's too much of a troubleshoot to deal with.

Comment: Strange thing actually, i've left it doing it's thing and despite it giving me that message about the UNC paths, it's still created a CSV file (currently 0kb) and seems to be doing something. Maybe it will still create it. I'll let you know soon enough.

Comment: That's worked! I'll do a few more tests on some more database files but that all seems to have worked so far. Looking like i'll be marking this as answered soon enough! Thanks LotPings!