# How do I create a ''droplet'' script in Linux that runs a Notepad++ task on a CSV file?

Tags: linux, powershell, notepad++, csv, bash-scripting

I have a BAT file that performs a 'Find & Replace' function on csv files when I drag & drop. This makes use of Powershell in Windows 7 but I now need the same thing to work on Linux instead.

I have no clue about Linux and barely ever used it before. Does anyone know if the same thing can be done in Linux with what was achieved in Powershell?

The batch script contents for what I've got going in Win7 is here:

```
:: SO_1352996.cmd
@Echo off
:Loop
If "%~1" equ "" goto :Eof
If not exist "%~1" (shift & goto :Loop)
Ren "%~f1" "%~n1_Original%~x1"
:: Use PowerShell as a tool to do the replace.
Powershell -NoP -C "(Get-Content '%~dpn1_Original%~x1') -replace '^([^,]*,(\d\d)_[^,]*,[^,]*)(?<!_\d\d),','$1_$2,' | Set-Content '%~f1'
Shift
Goto :Loop
```

It was originally a Notepad++ task I was manually running but was able to get it working as a batch script with help from the fine community superuser members here in my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1352996/how-do-i-create-a-droplet-script-in-win7-that-runs-a-notepad-task-on-a-csv) some time ago.

Is it possible to have a drag & drop 'droplet' to modify my CSV's in this way using Linux? I looked up what version of Linux I have by running `uname -a` in the command prompt and it's telling me that it's *Debian 3.16.59-1 (2018-10-03).*

Comment: Not sure that Linux users would know what a "droplet" is. Give them a plain script that takes the file as an argument and they will call it from their file explorer. The powershell bit can likely be replaced by a `sed` command with a little bit of adaptation .

Comment: Thanks xenoid. I'm completely in the dark about Linux. In the beginning I was exporting CSV files from the Linux server and passing them to my Win7 machine to perform the modifications but now I need to be able to perform the task directly off the server itself. Really not sure how to do this.

Comment: This is called shell scripting, a very common thing in Unix. Start something and ask questions when you are stuck. But read some introductory material/tutotial on bash first. if you can to Windows scripts, it is not that much different, it is even easier because the syntax is a bit cleaner.